# Is bijection map from a linear space also gives a linear space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider the set $\mathcal{C}$ of all absolutely continuous functions $([0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). So $\mathcal{C}$ is a linear space. For a $f\in \mathcal{C}$, let $g=Q(f)$ and $Q$ is a bijective map. Let the space of all $g$ is $\mathcal{S}$.

Is it true that $\mathcal{S}$ is a linear space?  I got stuck in showing that $g_1+g_2 \in \mathcal{S}$. Any ideas are welcome.

My try: Suppose $g^*=g_1+g_2$, then by bijective map, there always exists a $Q^{-1}$ such that $f^*=Q^{-1}(g^*)$. So $g^*\in \mathcal{S}$, implying $\mathcal{S}$ is a linear space.  Here I am not sure what am I missing.

Comment: No, of course not. A bijection tells you only that the sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: @user I added a proof which claims the linearity of the space (S).

Comment: Your proof is circular - you're assuming that $g^* \in S$ already, and then using its preimage to show it's in $S$.

Comment: @user Thanks. I get your point.